# Google maps + XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, html, google-maps

How can I test google maps APIs with XAMPP (as a localhost). Any help on this matter is highly appreciated. A proper tutorial link would be of great help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a blank php file and save it in htdocs of xampp.

Paste the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**YOUR_API_KEY**&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Replace the "your api key above" with a api key which you can get from the Google Maps website.

You are ready to go.